# How can I check if a watermelon is sweet or not when buying?

Tags: shopping, sweeteners, watermelon

I buy watermelon from the market, sometimes they are sweet and sometimes they are not. How can I check if a watermelon is sweet or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a farmer who was in love with his watermelons.

There are 2 things you want to check for when eating a watermelon A)ripeness B)sugar concentration

To tell if a watermelon is ripe check the pale spot on it’s belly. It should be yellow/white not green at all.

To test for sugar concentration tap on the watermelon, a dryer sweeter one will make a hollow sound while a wetter, watered down one will not make much of a sound.

That being said you don’t want a bone dry one as that means it’s probably old.